# why the getComputedValue of height value changes?

Tags: javascript

```js
var blueD = document.getElementById("blueDiv");
var blueStyle = window.getComputedStyle(blueDiv, null);
var hScrollHeight = (parseInt(blueStyle.getPropertyValue("height"),10) - blueD.clientHeight); // 15
alert(blueStyle.getPropertyValue("height")); // 185px
alert(blueD.clientHeight); // 185
```

```css
#blueDiv {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="blueDiv"></div>
```

My question is why the 1st alert method displays 185px when the #blueDiv element height is 200px? If I comment out the line that starts with "var hScrollHeight", then the 1st alert method correctly displays 200px.

Comment: Running your code with `//var hScrollHeight = ...` outputs 183 for me, so I can't replicate your problem. It is true that the scrollbar is deducting from the height computation, though.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on Chrome v67. Whether or not the line is commented out, I get 185 for both numbers. What browser and version does this occur on?

Comment: It works in Firefox 60.0.1 and not in Chrome 67.0.3396.79